# Any standard way to convert an ant project to Eclipse project?

Tags: java, ant, maven

For maven, we can use mvn eclispe:eclipse to do it. Any standard way if using ant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is eclipses File > New > Project... > Java > Java project from Existing Ant Buildfile good enough?